# How to automatically repeat HTML content in nunjucks?

Tags: html, node.js, template-engine, nunjucks, posthtml

This PostHTML plugin "[PostHTML Each](https://github.com/Gurylev/posthtml-each)" can repeat HTML code in a simple way. Like this

```
<!-- BEFORE -->
<div class="block" each="3"></div>

<!-- AFTER -->
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

How to repeat in a similar way in Nunjucks?

Comment: There's a for loop that you could probably use, see docs http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a nice one-liner as in your example for PostHTML but as mentioned in the comment you can use `for` tag. It needs a data source to iterate over, so use it with `range` function which will provide such.

```
{% for i in range(0, 3) -%}
  <div class="block"></div>
{%- endfor %}
```

Docs:

- [`for`](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#for) tag
- [`range`](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#range-start-stop-step) function